# Inner product of left and right eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a diagonalizable matrix $A=U\Lambda U^{-1}$ with real entries, we know that the columns of $U$ are right eigenvectors of $A$ (notice $AU=U\Lambda$) while the rows of $U^{-1}$ are left eigenvectors of $A$ (notice $U^{-1}A=\Lambda U^{-1}$). Let $u_i$ be the $i$th column of $U$ and $v_j^H$ be the $j$th row of $U^{-1}$. Then we know that $v_j^H u_i=1$ if $i=j$ and $v_j^H u_i=0$ otherwise. (Note that $v_j^H u_i=(U^{-1}U)_{ji}=I_{ji}$; $\{u_i\}$ and $\{v_j\}$ form a [dual basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis).)

Suppose that the dimension of $A$ is odd so that there exist a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ and its corresponding real $(u,v)$ pair such that $u^\top v=1$. My question is, if we throw away the negative entries of $v$ and obtain $v^+=\max(v,0)$ entry-wisely, what can we say about the inner product $u^\top v^+$?

- Is $u^\top v^+ \ge 0$?
- Is $|u^\top v^+|\le 1$?
- Any other properties?

I mentioned the above properties because they hold for symmetric $A$ with orthonormal $U$ ($u=v$ in this case).

Comment: I take it $\Lambda$ is diagonal. But "the" right eigenvectors is a nonsense, since, if $v$ is a right eigenvector, so is $\lambda v$ for any nonzero scalar $\lambda$. You are making some hidden assumptions about your matrix $U$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, you are right. I removed those "the"s.